# scrollTo doctype

Tags: jquery, doctype, scrollto

I am using the ScrollTo() jQuery plugin at the moment and it works fine whenever I do not define a Doctype, however when I define a Doctype, the ScrollTo() plugin breaks.

I have posted my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ianholden123/ScrollToDoctype)

I have looked through the internet for similar problems and I think some people have shared my problem but when looking at the solutions, they have not been clear to me.

I just need to get the plugin and doctype to work together, both must be present.
Please help,
Thanks

Comment: where is your code? show it here.

Comment: @Ian Holden: See my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: If you could link to a solution you do not understand, maybe someone could explain it to you. You might just get an answer that references something you've already stumbled upon but didn't grok? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Changes in your markup:

1. Replace your `jquery.scrollto.min.js` file with [**this version**](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js)
2. Replace `<ul class="threeNavLinks">...</ul>` with following code (both occurrence)

   ```
   <ul class="threeNavLinks">
       <li class="secondaryNavIcon"><a class="navlink" href="area2">About</a></li>
       <li class="primaryNavIcon"><a class="navlink" href="area3">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li class="secondaryNavIcon"><a class="navlink" href="area4">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. Add following script in `<head>`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
           $('.navlink').click(function(e) {
               var divId = '#' + $(this).attr("href");
               $.scrollTo(divId, 700);
               e.preventDefault();
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

The above solution is tested locally and working fine.

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue with the doctype declaration breaking this plugin on a validating site. Try testing with different versions of jQuery; I had a problem with 1.8.0 that was resolved by switching back to 1.7.0